# Wrap all methods of python superclass

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Is there a way to wrap all methods of a superclass, if I can't change its code?

As a minimal working example, consider this base class `Base`, which has many methods that return a new instance of itself, and the descendent class `Child`

```py
class Base:
    
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        
    def newinst_addseven(self):
        return Base(self.val + 7)
    
    def newinst_timestwo(self):
        return Base(self.val * 2)
    
    # ...

class Child(Base):
    
    @property
    def sqrt(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.val)
```

The issue here is that calling `childinstance.newinst_addseven()` returns an instance of `Base`, instead of `Child`.

**Is there a way to wrap the `Base` class's methods to force a return value of the type `Child`?**

With something like this wrapper:

```py
def force_child_i(result):
    """Turn Base instance into Child instance."""
    if type(result) is Base:
        return Child(result.val)
    return result

def force_child_f(fun):
    """Turn from Base- to Child-instance-returning function."""
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = fun(*args, **kwargs)
        return force_child_i(result)
    return wrapper
```

Many thanks!

---

PS: What I currently do, is look at `Base`'s source code and add the methods to `Child` directly, which is not very mainainable:

```
Child.newinst_addseven = force_child_f(Base.newinst_addseven)
Child.newinst_timestwo = force_child_f(Base.newinst_timestwo)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use a metaclass:

```py
class ChildMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        child = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        for base in bases:
            for field_name, field in base.__dict__.items():
                if callable(field):
                    setattr(child, field_name, force_child(field))
        return child


class Child(Base, metaclass=ChildMeta):
    pass
```

It will automatically wrap all the `Base`s methods with your `force_child` decorator.

Comment: Many thanks! While working on my specific case, this solution didn't work, and I'm unsure as to what's different. I've opened a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66120519/2302262) in case you might want to have a look. Thanks again.