# Wrapper around `pandas` `DataFrame` class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Using the `pandas` package, I often do similar calculations on `DataFrame` instances. To make things easier, I have created a class (`PfFrame`) which is a wrapper of `pandas.DataFrame` and has additional attributes I often use. This works:

```py
import pandas as pd

class PfFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    """PortfolioFrame; thin wrapper around pandas DataFrame."""
    # (here are the custom attributes of this class)
    pass
```

However, **all inherited methods, that return an instance of `pandas.DataFrame`, should be made to return an instance of `PfFrame` instead.** I implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65917217/2302262) pattern in the code below, but I'm getting an error - I'm thinking, due to the higher complexity of the base class.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def pf_i(val):
    """Turn DataFrame instance into PfFrame instance."""
    if type(val) is pd.DataFrame:
        val = PfFrame(val)
    return val

def pf_f(func):
    """Turn from DataFrame- to PfFrame-instance-returning function."""
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return pf_i(val)        
    return wrapper

class PfMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        klass = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        for base in bases:
            for field_name, field in base.__dict__.items():
                if callable(field):
                    setattr(klass, field_name, pf_f(field))
        return klass

class PfFrame(pd.DataFrame, metaclass=PfMeta):
    """PortfolioFrame; thin wrapper around pandas DataFrame."""
    # (here are the custom attributes of this class)
    pass
```

(I've reduced the code to the bare minimum and have left the specific attributes out, because my problem arises before that.)

**Any ideas to get this to work?**

Many thank!

### Additional info

#### 1

When creading an instance of the base and the child class, no errors are raised:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2), columns=list('ab'))
pfframe = PfFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2), columns=list('ab'))
```

However, doing *anything* with `pfframe` raises an error:

```
pfframe.a  # should return a pandas.Series
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'index'
pfframe[['a', 'b']]  # should return a PfFrame
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'index'
dir(pfframe)  # should return a simple dict
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'index'
```

#### 2

Still, passing it to the `pandas.DataFrame` constructor works fine:

```
pd.DataFrame(pfframe)
    a   b
0   0   1
1   2   3
2   4   5
```

#### 3

I thought the wrapping of the `__init__` method might by the problem. However, changing the `if callable(field):` line to adding `if callable(field) and field_name != "__init__":` makes no difference.

#### 4

Alternative solution: I currently only have a few attributes and *could* also attach them to `pd.DataFrame` directly, solving my problem in one step. However, I feel like this is poluting and makes things harder for users.

Comment: No-one? Anything I can do to better illustrate/explain the issue?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/