# How to wrap all python superclass methods with subclass internal state?

Tags: python, inheritance, wrapper, metaclass

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917217/wrap-all-methods-of-python-superclass) but I don't think it covers my case.

I have an external Dummy class with many methods, all using an instance attribute. Instead of using this instance attribute, I want to be able to pass it as an argument. My solution is to keep a collection of dummies, and use the one with the appropriate attribute when necessary.

```
class Dummy:

    def __init__(self, prefix="dum"):
        self.prefix = prefix

    def toto(self):
        return f"{self.prefix}_toto"

    def titi(self):
        return f"{self.prefix}_titi"

    def tata(self):
        return f"{self.prefix}_tata"


class DynamicDummy:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dummies = {}

    def _get_dummy(self, prefix):
        dummy = self.dummies.get(prefix)
        if dummy is None:
            dummy = Dummy(prefix)
            self.dummies[prefix] = dummy
        return dummy

    def toto(self, prefix):
        dummy = self._get_dummy(prefix)
        return dummy.toto()

    def titi(self, prefix):
        dummy = self._get_dummy(prefix)
        return dummy.titi()

    def tata(self, prefix):
        dummy = self._get_dummy(prefix)
        return dummy.tata()
```

The thing is, there are way more than 3 methods, and I want it to be automatic, such that I don't have to change my `DynamicDummy` everytime there is a change in `Dummy`. I have never used metaclass before, so maybe they are the solution, but I can't make them work with the `dummies` dictionnary, which is an instance attribute.

I am willing to go for a solution that makes it automatic, but also with an other solution altogether for the "dynamicity" problem.

Comment: why not have a single method like `get_name(self, name, prefix)` and call it like `get_name('toto', 'some_prefix')` instead of having multiple identical methods? That applies for both classes.

Comment: Also you may look at [customization of attribute access](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-module-attribute-access)

Comment: Because this is a simplified example, the actual methods are different from each others

Comment: Even in this case my advise to look at customisation of attribute access still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following @buran advice, I modified the `__getattribute__` method.

```
class SmartDynamicDummy(Dummy):

    def __init__(self):
        self.dummies = {}

    def _get_dummy(self, prefix):
        dummy = self.dummies.get(prefix)
        if dummy is None:
            dummy = Dummy(prefix)
            self.dummies[prefix] = dummy
        return dummy

    def _wrapper(self, func, func_name):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            args = list(args)
            prefix = args.pop(0)
            args = tuple(args)
            dummy = self._get_dummy(prefix)
            dummy_func = getattr(dummy, func_name)
            return dummy_func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapped


    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = super(SmartDynamicDummy, self).__getattribute__(name)
        if isinstance(attr, types.MethodType) and not name.startswith('_'):
            # attr.__name__ and name can be different if attr is a decorated function
            attr = self._wrapper(attr, name)
        return attr
```

Comment: The strategy is  good - but it is a bit more complicated than it should to keep the behavior a behavior you mentioned you don't want: this design still require the "dummy_collection" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `prefix` attribute on the target instance before you make your call, it will stay changed and just work- no need for a collection of instances with different values for `prefix`. The one case were the value could change midway is if your application is paralellized using threads - in that case, one of the other methods could be called on `DynamicDummy` requiring a different "prefix" before another call is over. This is the kind of problems that is solvable with `Locks`.

Metaclasses don't really have a role here. Sure, one could devise a complicated thing involving a metaclass, but we are just dealing iwth ordinary attribute setting;

So, in other words: if your program does not run in parallel, once you enter `SmartDummy.toto`, and this calls a Dummy instance `.toto()`, there is no way another method of the same Dummy instance will be called until both calls are resolved - so you can just set the desired value in `SmartDummy.toto`, before calling the method in the associated dummy instance.

If your code does run in parallel, but uses the `multiprocessing` model: the samething applies: in each process, instances of `SmartDummy` are run as if in a serial program, and no external thing can change the `prefix` attribute before `SmartDummy.toto` resolves.

If your code is parallel, but using `asyncio`, midway changes can just take place if the methods `toto`, `tata`, etc... are themselves async methods and yield the control to the async loop. If they are not declared as "async" it is guaranteed no code will run in parallel that could modify the attribute value (not even by some other function or method `Dummy.toto`  calls: if it is not "async", it can't yield execution to the loop. It can even schedule new tasks to be run, but those will only be touched when you return  the execution to the mainloop, and from a non-async function that happens the end of the function itself.

So, we are back to: just save the attribute value, make your call, and restore it. Add a Lock provision for the multi-thread case and you are fine.
Assuming you don't have access to the `Dummy` code, and that each instance of `DynamicDummy` fas one instance `Dummy` associated, we can create a lock at the `DynamicDummy` instance. If all `DynamicDummy`s would hare a single instance of `Dummy`, the lock would have to be a class attribute instead.

To call the wrapped methods in a transparent way, the design you got too is good: I am just changing it to use  `__getattr__` as it is simpler:

```
import threading

class DymamicDummy:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self.dummy = Dummy()
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        
    def _dispatcher(self, method):
        # the same thign you found your design: 
        # 'prefix' is always the first positional argument. Change it to a named parameter if desired.
        def wrapper(prefix, *args, **kwargs):
            with self.lock:
                original_prefix = self.dummy.prefix
                self.dummy.prefix = prefix
                try:
                    result = method(*args, **kwargs)
                finally:
                    self.dummy.prefix =self.dummy.prefix
            return result
            
        return wrapper
        
    def __getattr__(self, method_name):
        # using __getattr__ instead of __getattribute__:
        # this only gets called for methods or attributes that do not exist
        # on the current instance anyway: so no need to further testing,
        # just extract the value from Dummy.
        method = getattr(self.dummy, method_name)
        if not callable(method):
            return method
        return _dispatcher(method)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My real classes are not so simple. my "prefix" is actually a timezone, and each Dummy instance has a dataframe that is interpreted differently based on the timezone. Just changing the timezone would not be enough.